# Mocking itertools.zip_longest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-itertools

I've written some code to the effect of

```
def get_stuff(input):
    for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(input, input):
        # do some processing
        yield a, b
```

which currently is called as `get_stuff(sys.stdin)` but in the future may change to `get_stuff(some_file_I_opened)`. The reason I use `zip_longest` is to chunk the reading into pairs (ie: read two lines at a time). I'd like to mock `input` in my testing but I can't seem to get the mock to play nicely with `itertools.zip_longest`.

My mocking code right now:

```
def test_get_rover_information_happy_case(self):
    self.input = sys.stdin
    self.input = MagicMock()
    self.input.__iter__.return_value = ["5 5 N", "LRMR"]
    a, b = get_stuff(self.input)
```

What happens with this mocking code is that `get_stuff` is called twice. The first time it's called `a` and `b` both have the value `"5 5 N"` and the second time they both have the value `LRMR`.

How can I mock `input` such that two values are read at a time?

Comment: If I read your code, I would expect `a` and `b` to be the same values anyhow. Shouldn't you be passing two different values to `zip_longest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `return_value` an iterator over the `list`, rather than return the list object itself:

```
self.input.__iter__.return_value = iter(["5 5 N", "LRMR"])
```

Otherwise, each time `iter(input)` is called, the same list object is returned, and any iteration over it will start from index 0. By returning an iterator object, each iteration will pick up where the last one left off, which will simulate `sys.stdin` the way you want.